# print value of checked checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, foreach

```
if (isset($_POST['approve']))
{
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("shoolin",$con);
    $arr=$_POST['check'];
    foreach($arr as $selected)
    {
    echo $selected."</br>";
    }
}
```

i need to print the value of checkbox which is checked,so please suggest some solution to solve this problem of printing value of checkbox

This code shows an error in the foreach loop

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\user.php on line 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way..

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //to run PHP script on submit
        if (!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
            // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
            foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
                echo $selected."</br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that $arr is not an array

```
if (is_array($arr))
{
    foreach ($arr as $selected)
    {
        echo $selected."</br>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo $arr."</br>";
}
```